# Collapsible section with WAI-ARIA: additional "hide" button?

Tags: javascript, html, wai-aria

I'm using [this code snippet](https://codepen.io/heydon/pen/gGNaoM) (explained [here](https://inclusive-components.design/collapsible-sections/)) to create a collapsible section using WAI-ARIA. My collapsible text is very long though, so that I would like to add an additional "hide" button at the bottom of the text so that readers don't have to scroll up to click on the original button to collapse the section. I can't quite figure out how to get such a button to work. I would very much appreciate your help.

HTML:

```
<main> 
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque commodo purus quis mi cursus hendrerit eu eu metus. Aliquam aliquam arcu eget aliquet scelerisque. Pellentesque sodales turpis vitae venenatis vehicula.</p> 
    <p>Ut id porta velit. Ut eu dignissim dui, quis gravida est. Cras quis venenatis mauris, a bibendum enim. Sed at augue libero. Nullam tortor metus, tincidunt ut urna id, posuere placerat orci. Ut quis risus dictum risus facilisis imperdiet quis sed eros.</p>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <p>Nullam tortor metus, tincidunt ut urna id, posuere placerat orci.</p> 
    <p>Ut quis risus dictum risus facilisis imperdiet quis sed eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
    <p>Quisque commodo purus quis mi cursus hendrerit eu eu metus. Aliquam aliquam arcu eget aliquet scelerisque. Pellentesque sodales turpis vitae venenatis vehicula. Ut id porta velit. Ut eu dignissim dui, quis gravida est. Cras quis venenatis mauris, a bibendum enim. Sed at augue libero.</p>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  max-width: 40rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
}

main {
  border-width: 2px 0;
  border-style: solid;
}

main h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

main > div + h2 {
  border-top: 2px solid;
}

h2 button {
  all: inherit;
  border: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
}   
    
h2 button:focus svg {
  outline: 2px solid;
}

button svg {
  height: 1em;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

[aria-expanded="true"] .vert {
  display: none;
}

[aria-expanded] rect {
  fill: currentColor;
}

/* page styles */

html {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
 (function() {
  // Get all the <h2> headings
  const headings = document.querySelectorAll('main h2')
  
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(headings, heading => {
    // Give each <h2> a toggle button child
    // with the SVG plus/minus icon
    heading.innerHTML = `
      <button aria-expanded="false">
        ${heading.textContent}
        <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
          <rect class="vert" height="8" width="2" y="1" x="4"/>
          <rect height="2" width="8" y="4" x="1"/>
        </svg>
      </button>
    `
    
    // Function to create a node list 
    // of the content between this <h2> and the next
    const getContent = (elem) => {
      let elems = []
      while (elem.nextElementSibling && elem.nextElementSibling.tagName !== 'H2') {
        elems.push(elem.nextElementSibling)
        elem = elem.nextElementSibling
      }
      
      // Delete the old versions of the content nodes
      elems.forEach((node) => {
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node)
      })

      return elems
    }
    
    // Assign the contents to be expanded/collapsed (array)
    let contents = getContent(heading)
    
    // Create a wrapper element for `contents` and hide it
    let wrapper = document.createElement('div')
    wrapper.hidden = true
    
    // Add each element of `contents` to `wrapper`
    contents.forEach(node => {
      wrapper.appendChild(node)
    })
    
    // Add the wrapped content back into the DOM 
    // after the heading
    heading.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, heading.nextElementSibling)
    
    // Assign the button
    let btn = heading.querySelector('button')
    
    btn.onclick = () => {
      // Cast the state as a boolean
      let expanded = btn.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true' || false
      
      // Switch the state
      btn.setAttribute('aria-expanded', !expanded)
      // Switch the content's visibility
      wrapper.hidden = expanded    
    }
  })
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

what about to stick them on top so always you can collapse.

here is the example
https://jsfiddle.net/zb0xkuL5/

and this is the code

```
<html>
<body>
 

<main>
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque commodo purus quis mi cursus hendrerit eu eu metus. Aliquam aliquam arcu eget aliquet scelerisque. Pellentesque sodales turpis vitae venenatis vehicula.</p> 
    <p>Ut id porta velit. Ut eu dignissim dui, quis gravida est. Cras quis venenatis mauris, a bibendum enim. Sed at augue libero. Nullam tortor metus, tincidunt ut urna id, posuere placerat orci. Ut quis risus dictum risus facilisis imperdiet quis sed eros.</p>
    <p>Nullam tortor metus, tincidunt ut urna id, posuere placerat orci.</p> 
    <p>Ut quis risus dictum risus facilisis imperdiet quis sed eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
    <p>Quisque commodo purus quis mi cursus hendrerit eu eu metus. Aliquam aliquam arcu eget aliquet scelerisque. Pellentesque sodales turpis vitae venenatis vehicula. Ut id porta velit. Ut eu dignissim dui, quis gravida est. Cras quis venenatis mauris, a bibendum enim. Sed at augue libero.</p>
    <p>Nullam tortor metus, tincidunt ut urna id, posuere placerat orci.</p> 
    <p>Ut quis risus dictum risus facilisis imperdiet quis sed eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
    <p>Quisque commodo purus quis mi cursus hendrerit eu eu metus. Aliquam aliquam arcu eget aliquet scelerisque. Pellentesque sodales turpis vitae venenatis vehicula. Ut id porta velit. Ut eu dignissim dui, quis gravida est. Cras quis venenatis mauris, a bibendum enim. Sed at augue libero.</p>
    <p>Nullam tortor metus, tincidunt ut urna id, posuere placerat orci.</p> 
    <p>Ut quis risus dictum risus facilisis imperdiet quis sed eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
    <p>Quisque commodo purus quis mi cursus hendrerit eu eu metus. Aliquam aliquam arcu eget aliquet scelerisque. Pellentesque sodales turpis vitae venenatis vehicula. Ut id porta velit. Ut eu dignissim dui, quis gravida est. Cras quis venenatis mauris, a bibendum enim. Sed at augue libero.</p>
    <p>Nullam tortor metus, tincidunt ut urna id, posuere placerat orci.</p> 
    <p>Ut quis risus dictum risus facilisis imperdiet quis sed eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
    <p>Quisque commodo purus quis mi cursus hendrerit eu eu metus. Aliquam aliquam arcu eget aliquet scelerisque. Pellentesque sodales turpis vitae venenatis vehicula. Ut id porta velit. Ut eu dignissim dui, quis gravida est. Cras quis venenatis mauris, a bibendum enim. Sed at augue libero.</p>
    <p>Nullam tortor metus, tincidunt ut urna id, posuere placerat orci.</p> 
    <p>Ut quis risus dictum risus facilisis imperdiet quis sed eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
    <p>Quisque commodo purus quis mi cursus hendrerit eu eu metus. Aliquam aliquam arcu eget aliquet scelerisque. Pellentesque sodales turpis vitae venenatis vehicula. Ut id porta velit. Ut eu dignissim dui, quis gravida est. Cras quis venenatis mauris, a bibendum enim. Sed at augue libero.</p>
    <p>Nullam tortor metus, tincidunt ut urna id, posuere placerat orci.</p> 
    <p>Ut quis risus dictum risus facilisis imperdiet quis sed eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
    <p>Quisque commodo purus quis mi cursus hendrerit eu eu metus. Aliquam aliquam arcu eget aliquet scelerisque. Pellentesque sodales turpis vitae venenatis vehicula. Ut id porta velit. Ut eu dignissim dui, quis gravida est. Cras quis venenatis mauris, a bibendum enim. Sed at augue libero.</p>
    <p>Nullam tortor metus, tincidunt ut urna id, posuere placerat orci.</p> 
    <p>Ut quis risus dictum risus facilisis imperdiet quis sed eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
    <p>Quisque commodo purus quis mi cursus hendrerit eu eu metus. Aliquam aliquam arcu eget aliquet scelerisque. Pellentesque sodales turpis vitae venenatis vehicula. Ut id porta velit. Ut eu dignissim dui, quis gravida est. Cras quis venenatis mauris, a bibendum enim. Sed at augue libero.</p>

    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <p>Nullam tortor metus, tincidunt ut urna id, posuere placerat orci.</p> 
    <p>Ut quis risus dictum risus facilisis imperdiet quis sed eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
    <p>Quisque commodo purus quis mi cursus hendrerit eu eu metus. Aliquam aliquam arcu eget aliquet scelerisque. Pellentesque sodales turpis vitae venenatis vehicula. Ut id porta velit. Ut eu dignissim dui, quis gravida est. Cras quis venenatis mauris, a bibendum enim. Sed at augue libero.</p>
    <p>Nullam tortor metus, tincidunt ut urna id, posuere placerat orci.</p> 
    <p>Ut quis risus dictum risus facilisis imperdiet quis sed eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
    <p>Quisque commodo purus quis mi cursus hendrerit eu eu metus. Aliquam aliquam arcu eget aliquet scelerisque. Pellentesque sodales turpis vitae venenatis vehicula. Ut id porta velit. Ut eu dignissim dui, quis gravida est. Cras quis venenatis mauris, a bibendum enim. Sed at augue libero.</p>
    <p>Nullam tortor metus, tincidunt ut urna id, posuere placerat orci.</p> 
    <p>Ut quis risus dictum risus facilisis imperdiet quis sed eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
    <p>Quisque commodo purus quis mi cursus hendrerit eu eu metus. Aliquam aliquam arcu eget aliquet scelerisque. Pellentesque sodales turpis vitae venenatis vehicula. Ut id porta velit. Ut eu dignissim dui, quis gravida est. Cras quis venenatis mauris, a bibendum enim. Sed at augue libero.</p>
    <p>Nullam tortor metus, tincidunt ut urna id, posuere placerat orci.</p> 
    <p>Ut quis risus dictum risus facilisis imperdiet quis sed eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
    <p>Quisque commodo purus quis mi cursus hendrerit eu eu metus. Aliquam aliquam arcu eget aliquet scelerisque. Pellentesque sodales turpis vitae venenatis vehicula. Ut id porta velit. Ut eu dignissim dui, quis gravida est. Cras quis venenatis mauris, a bibendum enim. Sed at augue libero.</p>
    <p>Nullam tortor metus, tincidunt ut urna id, posuere placerat orci.</p> 
    <p>Ut quis risus dictum risus facilisis imperdiet quis sed eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
    <p>Quisque commodo purus quis mi cursus hendrerit eu eu metus. Aliquam aliquam arcu eget aliquet scelerisque. Pellentesque sodales turpis vitae venenatis vehicula. Ut id porta velit. Ut eu dignissim dui, quis gravida est. Cras quis venenatis mauris, a bibendum enim. Sed at augue libero.</p>
    <p>Nullam tortor metus, tincidunt ut urna id, posuere placerat orci.</p> 
    <p>Ut quis risus dictum risus facilisis imperdiet quis sed eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
    <p>Quisque commodo purus quis mi cursus hendrerit eu eu metus. Aliquam aliquam arcu eget aliquet scelerisque. Pellentesque sodales turpis vitae venenatis vehicula. Ut id porta velit. Ut eu dignissim dui, quis gravida est. Cras quis venenatis mauris, a bibendum enim. Sed at augue libero.</p>
    <p>Nullam tortor metus, tincidunt ut urna id, posuere placerat orci.</p> 
    <p>Ut quis risus dictum risus facilisis imperdiet quis sed eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
    <p>Quisque commodo purus quis mi cursus hendrerit eu eu metus. Aliquam aliquam arcu eget aliquet scelerisque. Pellentesque sodales turpis vitae venenatis vehicula. Ut id porta velit. Ut eu dignissim dui, quis gravida est. Cras quis venenatis mauris, a bibendum enim. Sed at augue libero.</p>

</main>  </body>
</html>
<style>  
 body {
  max-width: 40rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
}

main {
  border-width: 2px 0;
  border-style: solid;
}

main h2 {
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

main > div + h2 {
  border-top: 2px solid;
}

h2 button {
  all: inherit;
  border: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
}



h2 button:focus svg {
  outline: 2px solid;
}

button svg {
  height: 1em;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

[aria-expanded="true"] .vert {
  display: none;
}

[aria-expanded] rect {
  fill: currentColor;
}

/* page styles */

html {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
<script>  
    (function() {
   // Get all the <h2> headings
   const headings = document.querySelectorAll('main h2')
   
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(headings, heading => {
     // Give each <h2> a toggle button child
     // with the SVG plus/minus icon
     heading.innerHTML = `
       <button aria-expanded="false">
         ${heading.textContent}
         <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
           <rect class="vert" height="8" width="2" y="1" x="4"/>
           <rect height="2" width="8" y="4" x="1"/>
         </svg>
       </button>
     `
     
     // Function to create a node list 
     // of the content between this <h2> and the next
     const getContent = (elem) => {
       let elems = []
       while (elem.nextElementSibling && elem.nextElementSibling.tagName !== 'H2') {
         elems.push(elem.nextElementSibling)
         elem = elem.nextElementSibling
       }
       
       // Delete the old versions of the content nodes
       elems.forEach((node) => {
         node.parentNode.removeChild(node)
       })
 
       return elems
     }
     
     // Assign the contents to be expanded/collapsed (array)
     let contents = getContent(heading)
     
     // Create a wrapper element for `contents` and hide it
     let wrapper = document.createElement('div')
     wrapper.hidden = true
     
     // Add each element of `contents` to `wrapper`
     contents.forEach(node => {
       wrapper.appendChild(node)
     })
     
     // Add the wrapped content back into the DOM 
     // after the heading
     heading.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, heading.nextElementSibling)
     
     // Assign the button
     let btn = heading.querySelector('button')
     
     btn.onclick = () => {
       // Cast the state as a boolean
       let expanded = btn.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true' || false
       
       // Switch the state
       btn.setAttribute('aria-expanded', !expanded)
       // Switch the content's visibility
       wrapper.hidden = expanded    
     }
   })
 })()
      </script>
```

Comment: I really like that! Unfortunately, I can't use Bootstrap in my current project though :( Thanks so much anyway!

Comment: Thanks! but you don't need bootstrap over there, this is by mistake..
look at this now https://jsfiddle.net/moti013/2ducyLnr/